# Match substrings and only keep the highest value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to search an array for duplicate values in each subarray and if there is one, only keep the highest value connected to this item.

That's my question, but I love to add an example to clarify things!

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 1
            [points]  => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 1
            [points]  => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 1
            [points]  => 4
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 2
            [points]  => 1
        )
)
```

As you can see, the first three items have the same `groupid`. I want to match those items and see which of them has the highest points. The other one (with the lowest points) should be kicked out of the array.

So in this case, item `0`, `1` and `2` are from the same group, but `2` has the highest points. `0` and `1` should be dropped out of the array.

My desired result would be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 1
            [points]  => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [groupid] => 2
            [points]  => 1
        )
)
```

I've been trying for a few hours now but no luck yet. Maybe I am overlooking something very simple and thinking to hard to figure this out... Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**
It's a Drupal site (but that shouldn't make any difference) and this is query:

```
foreach ($promotions as $value) {
   $promo = db_query("SELECT * FROM {_promo_articles} WHERE art = :art AND promoid = :promoid", array(
        ':art'      => $value['product'][0]->sku,
        ':promoid'  => $value['promo_id'][0])) ->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Is this information coming from a  database? If so, then it might be much easier to query from the DB.

Comment: naive approach like, make an array with unique value(values are groupids). Then iterate over that array and find the max for every groupid in this array?

Comment: @Neal, yes it does... I was thinking of this as well, but how would you do this?

Comment: `SELECT *, max(points) AS max_points FROM database GROUP BY groupid`

Comment: Query with `max(points) group by goupid` clause.

Comment: Happy to help @Pieter :-D

Answer (score 4):

As I see from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655615/match-substrings-and-only-keep-the-highest-value#comment25712945_17655615), the information is coming from the database so do something like this:

(pseudocode)

```
SELECT group_id, MAX(points) 
FROM db_table
GROUP BY group_id;
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but the issue is I have to query the database every time in a `foreach` loop... So I'm afraid this isn't a solution...

Comment: @Michiel eh? Why are you querying in a `foreach` loop? just get all the data before the loop! :-D

Comment: Because each query has a different parameter :)

Comment: @Michiel again... so why not query it all at once?

Comment: I'll add my (Drupal) query to the question, maybe it will help make myself clear!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like :

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($array AS $element)
{
    if(!isset($final_array[$element["groupid"]]) ||
       $final_array[$element["groupid"]] < $element["points"])
            $final_array[$element["groupid"]] = $element["points"];
}
```

Then, `$final_array` would look like...

```
Array
(
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 1
)
```

(group 1 has 5 points, group 2 has 1 point)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function to order your array in order by `points`. This function will order it from greatest to least:

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['points'] - $a['points'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments the best way to do this is from your database if that is an option.

If not you can use array_reduce and a closure (PHP 5.3+)

```
 $array = array_reduce($array,function(&$result, $val){ 
                         if (!array_key_exists($val["groupid"], $result){
                           $result[$val["groupid"]] = $val;    
                         } else {
                           if ($result[$val["groupid"]]["points"] < $val["points"])
                               $result[$val["groupid"]]["points"] = $val["points"];  
                         }
                       }, array());
```

Then if you want to reset the keys

```
$array = array_values($array);
```